# How many times the most I can change the background of the pushButton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

So , I am trying to blink the push button with the color that I pass and between white. And it only seems to blink it so many times after that code would crash. 
I have tried it to implement the blinking with different blink rates and it 
would it still break at some time.

- in 'a' I have the string like "Background-color: rgb(255,0,0)".
- in 'timings' i have a list like[208, 280]or it could be [48,32,48,32,100,280], this represents the on and off timings 'zeroth index' represents on and 'index 1' represents off time and follows the pattern so on.

```py
while True:
    i = 0
    while i < len(timings):
        if self.p[2] == 1:
            self.b.setStyleSheet("{}".format(a))
            self.b.update()
            time.sleep(timings[i]/1000)
            self.b.setStyleSheet("Background-color: rgb(255,255,255)")
            self.b.update()
            time.sleep(timings[i+1]/1000)
            i = i + 2
```

self.head1, self.head2, self.head3 all have list with some thing like this ["Background-color:rgb(255,0,0)",list of on and off patterns, head number#]

right now, I am working with three heads.

```
def flash(self):
    obj1 = threads(self.head1, self.head1_pb)
    obj2 = threads(self.head2, self.head2_pb)
    obj3 = threads(self.head3, self.head3_pb)
    obj1.start()
    time.sleep(.02)
    obj2.start()
    time.sleep(.02)
    obj3.start()

class threads(Thread):

    def __init__(self, a, pb):
         Thread.__init__(self)
         self.p = a
         self.b = pb

    def run(self):

       a = self.p[0]
       timings = self.p[1]
       print(timings[0])
       while True:
           i = 0
           while i < len(timings):
                if self.p[2] == 1:
                   self.b.setStyleSheet("{}".format(a))
                   self.b.update()
                   time.sleep(timings[i]/1000)
                   self.b.setStyleSheet("Background-color: rgb(255,255,255)")
                   self.b.update()
                   time.sleep(timings[i+1]/1000)
                   i = i + 2
               elif self.p[2] == 2:
                   self.b.setStyleSheet("{}".format(a))
                   self.b.update()
                   time.sleep(timings[i]/1000)
                   self.b.setStyleSheet("Background-color: rgb(255,255,255)")
                   self.b.update()
                   time.sleep(timings[i+1]/1000)
                   i = i + 2
              else:
                   self.b.setStyleSheet("{}".format(a))
                   self.b.update()
                   time.sleep(timings[i]/1000)
                   self.b.setStyleSheet("Background-color: rgb(255,255,255)")
                   self.b.update()
                   time.sleep(timings[i+1]/1000)
                   i = i + 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color as many times as you want, the problem is that you should not use a time consuming loop or use time.sleep() because they block the eventloop generating the GUI to freeze. Instead, use a QTimer to call the task that changes color every so often.

In the following example, create a custom button that implements what you want:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._color = QtGui.QColor("white")
        timer_on = QtCore.QTimer(singleShot=True, timeout=self.on_timeout)
        timer_off = QtCore.QTimer(singleShot=True, timeout=self.on_timeout)
        self._timers = (timer_on, timer_off)
        for timer, function in zip(self._timers, (self.on, self.off)):
            timer.timeout.connect(function)

    def setTime(self, on_time, off_time):
        for t, timer in zip((on_time, off_time), self._timers):
            timer.setInterval(t)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_timeout(self):
        timer = self.sender()
        if timer not in self._timers:
            return
        timer_on, timer_off = self._timers
        another_timer = timer_off if timer is timer_on else timer_on
        another_timer.start()

    def start(self):
        timer_on, _ = self._timers
        timer_on.start()

    def stop(self):
        for timer in self._timers:
            timer.stop()
        self.off()

    def color(self):
        return self._color

    def setColor(self, color):
        if self.color() == color:
            return
        self._color = color

    def on(self):
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """PushButton{ background-color: %s}""" % (self.color().name(),)
        )

    def off(self):
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """PushButton{ background-color: rgb(255,255,255)}"""
        )


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        button = PushButton()
        button.setColor(QtGui.QColor("salmon"))
        button.setTime(208, 280)
        button.start()

        # stop blink in 30 seconds
        # QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(30 * 1000, button.stop)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Plus:**

As you note that you have a lot of data, it is best to create an iterator to save memory. Considering the above I have created a QPushButton that obtains the data from the iterator.

```py
import random
from functools import partial
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def generate_data():
    i = 0
    while i < 1000000:
        color_on = random.randint(10, 500)
        color_off = random.randint(10, 500)
        color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))
        yield color_on, color_off, color
        i += 1


class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._color = QtGui.QColor("white")
        self._generator = None

        self.m_timer = QtCore.QTimer(
            self, timeout=self.on_timeout, singleShot=True
        )

    def setGenerator(self, generator):
        self._generator = generator

    def start(self):
        self.on_timeout()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_timeout(self):
        try:
            time_on, time_off, color = next(self._generator)
            self.setColor(color)
            self.m_timer.start(time_on + time_off)
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(
                time_on, partial(self.setColor, QtGui.QColor("white"))
            )
        except StopIteration:
            self.m_timer.stop()

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """PushButton{ background-color: %s}""" % (color.name(),)
        )


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        for _ in range(6):
            button = PushButton()
            button.setGenerator(generate_data())
            button.start()
            lay.addWidget(button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Awesome. But I am doing it in a different thread. Wouldnt it make any difference ?

Comment: @JunaidKhalid You should not update the GUI (button) from another thread, Qt forbids it: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread.  IMHO you should only use the threads as a last resort, and in this case it is not necessary since you do not have any heavy tasks, changing the color of a button consumes a very small amount of time.

Comment: @eyllansec my list represents the pattern like on and off pattern. And it can be a big list.  I have edited  in the question too.

Comment: @JunaidKhalid use an iterator plus a QTimer, I still do not see the editing.

Comment: @eyllansec I am trying to implement the Led light bar. with different heads what I want to do eventually is light up each head of the light bar with different patterns.

Comment: @JunaidKhalid provide a [MRE] and then I could help you.

Comment: @eyllansec I edited the whole time. Check it out and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @JunaidKhalid I'm interested in knowing how the patterns generate or better the function that generates it. Also avoid using "#" in your sentences.

Comment: patterns are just list of random numbers like [ 160, 44, 160, 364] and it represents [on,off,on,off]

Comment: @JunaidKhalid Well, I implement the logic in my own way and if the method that generates the data influences the resolution of the problem, in that case you will have to take care of it, I will follow my path and I will say goodbye. In conclusion, I do not like to change the logic of my answers or invest much time in it just because the OP does not provide the information, for example you did not speak of threading at the beginning.

Comment: your code is impressive. But there are few things That I dont get it. Could you please help me with that as I am only the beginner.
@QtCore.Slot() this decorator I dont understand it and inside here I dont know where time_on ,time_off, color = next(self.generator) coming from like what is the purpose.
    :

Comment: @JunaidKhalid 1) Read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator 2) Read about iterators: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next , https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement

Comment: @eyllansec can you explain me this line of code"

 self.m_timer = QtCore.QTimer(
            self, timeout=self.on_timeout, singleShot=True
        )
"

Comment: @JunaidKhalid When you ask for an explanation of something you have to point out that you do not understand that something

Comment: @eyllansec sure my bad. I dont understand what is the purpose of the 2nd argument "timeout = self.on_timeout" and singleShot.

I have tried to read the documentation but It is still not clear to me.

Comment: @JunaidKhalid  1) Do you know and understand the concept of signals and slots in the context of Qt? 2) A QTimer is a class that allows executing a certain task at a certain time, this can be only once or periodically, when you activate the singleShot flag, the first case is used.

Comment: @eyllansec Yes I do understand that concept. But why are you calling that 'on_timeout' function and setting equal to the timeout argument there?

Comment: @eyllansec so by what I know signal is emitted when a particular event occurs and slot is the function that gets called in response to the event.

Comment: @eyllansec also I dont know why they dont have good documentation and tutorial for pyside2 framework in python. There is just a lot more information for C++

Comment: @JunaidKhalid 1) Great, so instead of writing self.m_timer.timeout.connect (self.on_timeout) I put it in the constructor. 2) Because Qt is written in C ++, when I provide you with a link my idea is that you review the concepts since they are kept in any language. The conversation has already spread so I will not answer, bye

Comment: @eyllansec Thank you for your time and help. Good day!

Comment: @eyllansec I understood the code. But when I pass same the same flash pattern to lets say 5 buttons, they dont blink in sync. They start blink out of sync after some time. Any Thoughts how to fix that?